# requirejs - Cannot define named module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm currently working with requirejs. I'm trying to define a specific, existing object as a module, but I can't get it to work.

Actually, I'm using an example from their website: http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#namedmodules

```
> define('myModule', [], function () {
>    return function () {};
> });
undefined

> requirejs('myModule')
undefined

> requirejs.defined('myModule')
false
```

In this shell, both requirejs and define exist, and are coming from requirejs.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can only? fetch the module using the specified callback in require:

```
define('myModule', [], function () {
   return function () {};
});
requirejs(['myModule'], function(myModule) {
  console.log(myModule);
});
```

Comment: When I do that, `console.log(myModule)` prints the `requirejs` function. However, once that step is done, `myModule` can be loaded via a `var myModule = requirejs('myModule');`. That sounds weird, is there something to know about it?

Comment: This works cause, once loaded the callback is not necessary anymore.